# Empty screen phpinfo() in apache Mac 10.10

Tags: php, apache, homebrew, osx-yosemite

Why php installed with hombrew working in console, but in apache, i see empty screen. (127.0.0.1/info.php with phpinfo())

in

> /etc/apache/httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php54/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are pointing at the wrong binary.  Change the line in httpd.conf to something like: `/usr/localCellar/php55/5.5.18/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`, or wherever brew placed PHP, and then restart apache.

You should also be getting errors in your logs which can help diagnose these issues.  Always check the logs.  The command `which php` can show which php binary is in use on the command line.  You can have multiple versions installed without issue, you will need to tell apache which one to use though.

Comment: in logs on Nov 24 22:48:33.489801 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 50] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Mon Nov 24 22:48:33.662420 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 483] AH00163: Apache/2.4.9 (Unix) PHP/5.5.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Mon Nov 24 22:48:33.662479 2014] [core:notice] [pid 483] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'

Comment: And I change path to /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so But see only empty screen(  which php (/usr/local/bin/php)

Comment: Go to the bin folder in that 5.5.19 directory and see if your php install works at all... `./php -v` or something.  Did you have any errors when you had brew install it?  Assuming you took recent mac updates ensure xcode command like tools are current.

Comment: /usr/local/Cellar/php55/5.5.19/bin/php -v                          PHP 5.5.19 (cli) (built: Nov 24 2014 17:41:15) No errors on install,  xcode install, all updates and xcode-select --install

Comment: I can't understand that. I re-install OS X, re-install brew and see only empty screen(

Comment: Hmm, I'd go back to those logs again, what you pasted looks like normal startup chatter of worker spawning process.  Maybe try `httpd -t` to check httpd conf syntax.  Other changes with mac updates... double check user/group in httpd conf.  Might be a permission issue.  Again though with out something to go on from the logs its a crap shoot.

Comment: httpd -t (Syntax OK) httpd.conf is default                       (User _www
Group _www)                                                 DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">                         if I change php_module dir to default libexec/apache2/libphp5.so, I see phpinfo() in localhost. Problem only with brew php.

Comment: Not running 5.5.19 myself.  Maybe try 5.5.18 see if that works.  Good luck.

Comment: try it tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Oooo, I found problem. I try call phpinfo() by <? phpinfo() ?>

Comment: error logs are your friend :)